# 'charmap' codec can't encode character error in Python while parsing HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

Here is my code:

```
dataFile = open('dataFile.html', 'w')
res = requests.get('site/pm=' + str(i))
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
linkElems = soup.select('#content')
dataFile.write(str(linkElems[0]))
```

I have some other code to but this is the code that I think is problematic. I have also tried using:

```
dataFile.write(str(linkElems[0].decode('utf-8')))
```

but that does not work and gives error.

Using `dataFile = open('dataFile.html', 'wb')` gives me the error:

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened your text file without specifying an encoding:

```
dataFile = open('dataFile.html', 'w')
```

This tells Python to use the *default codec for your system*. Every Unicode string you try to write to it will be encoded to that codec, and your Windows system is not set up with UTF-8 as the default.

Explicitly specify the encoding:

```
dataFile = open('dataFile.html', 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

Next, you are trusting the HTTP server to know what encoding the HTML data is using. This is usually not set at all, so don't use `response.text`! It is not BeautifulSoup at fault here, you are re-encoding a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). The `requests` library will default to Latin-1 encoding for `text/*` content types when the server doesn't explicitly specify an encoding, because the HTTP standard states that that is the default.

See the [*Encoding* section of the *Advanced* documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#encodings):

> The only time Requests will not do this is if no explicit charset is present in the HTTP headers *and* the `Content-Type` header contains `text`. **In this situation, RFC 2616 specifies that the default charset must be `ISO-8859-1`**. Requests follows the specification in this case. If you require a different encoding, you can manually set the `Response.encoding` property, or use the raw `Response.content`.

Bold emphasis mine.

Pass in the `response.content` raw data instead:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
```

BeautifulSoup 4 usually does a great job of figuring out the right encoding to use when parsing, either from a HTML `<meta>` tag or statistical analysis of the bytes provided. If the server does provide a characterset, you can still pass this into BeautifulSoup from the response, but do test first if `requests` used a default:

```
encoding = res.encoding if 'charset' in res.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() else None
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser', encoding=encoding)
```

Comment: There is still one problem. I get weird characters like `âˆ’` instead of a regular `-` now.

Comment: Is their any way to store this data in binary format?

Comment: @SanJeetSingh: you are using `response.text`. Don't, that'll use the default Latin-1 for HTTP text responses without a Content-type encoding set, and that is invariably wrong. Use `response.content` and leave it to BeautifulSoup to figure out the encoding to use.

Comment: @SanJeetSingh: You have *text*, so treat it as such, just fix the Mojibake you introduced by using `response.text`.

Comment: @SanJeetSingh: *binary format* does not make much sense for text data containing non ascii characters. And the *minus sign* (unicode character U+2212) will be hard to find in non unicode charsets - `âˆ’` is `'\xe2\x88\x92'`, the utf8 representation of `u'\u2212'`

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I  use, `response.content` will it resolve all issues related to content encoding in HTML and not show any weird characters? I am sorry if this question is stupid but I am very new to this thing.

Comment: @SanJeetSingh: when you use `response.content` in then BeautifulSoup will try to determine what codec to use to decode to Unicode. The HTML content can contain a `<meta>` header that explicitly documents what codec is used, and if not statistical analysis is used to make a guess. So it *could* still go wrong. But if the server didn't tell you what codec is to be used and the HTML doesn't contain that info, you are no worse off anyway. This is what browsers have to do too, and they do this in exactly the same manner.